# Problemas com toDataUrl

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Estou tentando exportar para um arquivo de texto o conteúdo de um `canvas` com `toDataUrl()`, mas estou recebendo esse erro:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on
> 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported

Pesquisei um pouco e descobri que não é possível usar o `toDataUrl` com imagens de origens "cruzadas", mas o problema é que minha imagem é local.

Este é o código atual:

```
const cnv = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');

const img = new Image;
img.src='./img/mydraw.png';

ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,300,140,0,0,300,140);
 
var image = cnv.toDataURL();
 
var blob = new Blob([image]);
saveAs(blob,'image.txt')
```

Comment: Qual é o caminho absoluto da imagem?

Comment: Quando diz que a imagem é "local" é localhost, file, algum IP, ou testou isso em um domínio específico?

Comment: A imagem é localhost